# How to use DetailView to override the view of an object that does not exists?

Tags: django, admin

I want to override the admin default detail view for an object to use a different template when the object does not exist, i.e.

```
<mydomain>/admin/<myapp>/<mymodel>/<someidthatdoesexist>/
```

should render the default object detail view, and

```
<mydomain>/admin/<myapp>/<mymodel>/<someidthatdoesNOTexist>/
```

should render a custom template, instead of the default 404 error.

From what I've read I should use `django.views.generic.detail.DetailView`, but I'm not sure how I can achieve what I want.

I tried:

```
<b>in urls.py</b>

    url(r'^admin/<myapp>/<mymodel>/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.MyModelDetailView.as_view(), name='mymodel_detail'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

<b>in models.py</b>

class MyModelDetailView(DetailView):

    model = MyModel

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.model.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])           
            return super(MyModelDetailView, self).get(request, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            # render custom template
```

but I get a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error:

```
<myapp>/mymodel_detail.html
```

What template should I set to render the default object detail view when the object exists?

**EDIT**

From the example given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), no template needs to be set...

Comment: Confused - you want to render a template if the object doesn't exist, but the code currently performs a redirect in that case?  Is that a typo, or intentional?

Comment: You're right. I want the default page when the object exists, and a custom page rendering a custom template when it does not. I edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

The `DetailView` does not raise `TemplateDoesNotExist` anywhere in its source code. So the only probable place where the exception is being raised is in your redirect (`return redirect(url)`).

By the way a very useful place to browse class-based-views code is classy views at http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

As for rendering a custom template if the object does not exist, you can easily modify your `get` function to make that work:

```
class MyModelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'object_is_found.html' # <= make sure to have this

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except Http404:
            # return custom template
            return render(request, 'no_object.html', status=404)
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: When doing this, I still get TemplateDoesNotExist.

Comment: are you sure you are providing the correct template name to the render?

Comment: make sure the directory for that template is within your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`

Comment: I have this error even when the object exists, so I guess this is related to as_view() in my urls.py. Is it the correct way to call the DetailView? I'd like not to specify any template for the default behaviour, and only specify one when rendering one in the Http404 exception of MyModelDetailView.get()

Comment: oh. in this case you are just not providing the detail view the template it should use when the object is found. You can do that either by providing it in the class definition by giving `template_name` attribute or you can pass it in `as_view`.

Comment: I also modified the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I don't have any 'object_is_found.html' template. It should use the default one, i.e. the one used by the default admin for all models.

Comment: In that case you should subclass the default `DetailView` Django admin uses. I don't know where it is though.

Comment: Ok, so I might not use DetailView for that.

Comment: I just looked at Django Admin code and it does not seem that they are using class based views. Why did you try to implement this with a class based view to begin with?

Comment: I though that would be easier. What's the standard way to do what I want?

Comment: I don't know. I think Class Based Views are a new standard for views. They are a bit confusing at first but after awhile it becomes second nature plus they offer many benefits over regular views. As for Django Admin, I don't know too much how to customize it other then registering custom admin models.